# Where does openrefine store projects?

Tags: openrefine

I would like to know where does openrefine store projects' information. I've version controlled openrefine's folder but apparently none of its contents have been changed so I guess that there must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projects and files are stored on your computer but not in the downloaded OpenRefine folder. The possible storage locations (depending on your OS) are listed in the OpenRefine Wiki under Installation: https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/installing#set-where-data-is-stored

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't really sound like a programming question (and it's covered in the user documentation on the wiki), but if you click "Browse workspace directory" on the main screen it will take you to -- wait for it -- the workspace directory.  Each project is a sub-directory beneath there.